# fastlane: Ruby environment variable ENV['PWD'] return nil/empty path

Tags: ruby, fastlane

In the ruby script for fastlane, I am trying to access an environment variable `ENV['PWD']`, but it returns as empty path/nil.

When I execute command `env` from mac terminal, it shows `PWD=/abcd/project`

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more code/details - `ENV['PWD']` works as expected o my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Quitting terminal and launching terminal again, it starts working!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the process's current directory, use `Dir.pwd`.

If you want to get the value of the environment variable, use `ENV['PWD']`.

You can use `ps awwxue` command to inspect the environment of running processes to figure out why your process doesn't have `PWD` set.

One way of clearing the environment is to use `env -`, e.g. `env - env`.